$\frac{1}{8}x^2+\frac{23}{9}y^2=z^2$ has non-trivial solutions $\in \mathbb{Q}$
For context: I am learning about the Hasse-Minkowski Theorem and Hilbert-Symbols.
I am trying to understand the solution of the following example:
Consider the equation $\frac{1}{8}x^2+\frac{23}{9}y^2=z^2$. We will show that this equation has non-trivial solutions in $\mathbb{Q}$.
My Problem is the beginning:

Because of $\frac{1}{8}=\frac{2}{4^2}$ and
$\frac{23}{9}=\frac{23}{3^2}$ we can instead consider the equation
$2x^2+23y^2=z^2$.

I can't comprehend why we can do this. And given an equation how to get there.

Cassels, Rational Quadratic Forms, has a nice table of the Hilbert symbol on page 43.

I'm assuming there is a typo and you meant 23 instead of 24 for the coefficient of $y^2$.
$(x,y,z)$ is a solution to $\frac18 x^2 + \frac{23}9y^2=z^2$ if and only if $(\frac x4,\frac y3,z)$ is a solution to $2x^2+23y^2=z^2$.
And of course, $x,y,z\in \mathbb Q$ if and only if $\frac x4,\frac y3,z \in\mathbb Q$, so the existence of a solution to the first equation implies the existence of a solution to the second.

Yes, it should have been $23$. I did correct it. Thank you for your answer.

You want to show that, using the Hilbert symbol, that
$$ \left( \tfrac{1}{8}, \tfrac{23}{9} \right)_p = +1 $$
for all primes $p$, including $p=\infty$.
The case when $p=\infty$ is trivial since you are asking whether the quadratic form has a rational point over $\mathbb{R}$, which is clearly does.
Recall that the Hilbert symbol is unchanged under squares i.e. $(a,b)_p = (c^2a,b)_p$. Thus, we can simply and say that,
$$ \left( \tfrac{1}{8}, \tfrac{23}{9} \right)_p = \left( 16\cdot \tfrac{1}{8}, 9\cdot \tfrac{23}{9} \right)_p = (2,23)_p $$
I will leave the case when $p=2$ for you to think about. But for now assume that $p$ is a finite prime and $p\not = 2$.
Either $p\not = 23$ or $p=23$. If $p\not = 23$ then both $2$ and $23$ are inveritble (mod $p$), this immedialely implies that $(2,23)_p = +1$. If you are unsure why, you can look at the Hilbert symbol computation formula in "Course in Arithmetic" by Serre.
If, however, $p=23$, then, by using the Hilbert symbol formula again, we find,
$$(2,23)_{23} = (2/23) $$
where the right-hand-side is interpreted as the Legendre symbol.
A simple computation will then show that $(2/23) = +1$.
Thus, we have shown that the quadratic form is locally solvable for each prime $p$.

and all integer solutions to $2x^2  + 23 y^2 = z^2$  with $\gcd(x,y,z) = 1$  and $x,y,z \geq 0$  come from
$$   x = |u^2 + 10 uv + 2 v^2| \, , \; \; y = |u^2 - 2 v^2| \, , \; \; z = 5 u^2 + 4 uv + 10 v^2 \; .  $$
Not a coincidence, $u^2 + 10 uv + 2 v^2 = (u+5v)^2 -23 v^2  $
Just one of those things. Mordell, Diophantine Equations, on page 47, shows that the set of "solutions"  of an indefinite ternary   are given by a finite set of Pythagorean Triple type parametrizations.

